# how to set media playback time to progressView using AVAudioPlayer in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nstimer

i have tried the following code

count += 2

```
    if count > 100 {
        soundRecorder?.stop()

        if player != nil {
            if player!.isPlaying {
                player!.stop()
            }
        }

        print("Recording complete")

    }

    soundRecorder?.updateMeters()

    if !(soundRecorder?.isRecording)! {
        visualizerTimer?.invalidate()
        visualizerTimer = nil
    }
    else {
        self.progressView.setProgress(visualizerTimer, animated: true) // receiving error for "Cannot convert value of type 'Timer?' to expected argument type 'Float'"
        print("Recording")
    }
```

i want the progressView should move according to recording audio size , if audio plays for 1 minute then progressView should move according to audio time.
Please help me to solve this problem.***

Comment: User observer or notificationcenter with timer

Comment: can you tell me how to do that ? or you can edit above code please ?

Comment: using addPeriodicTimeObserver(:_:_:)

Comment: please write with code

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this code, it my be help's you

```
 let intervel = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 2)
            player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: intervel, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (progressTime) in

                let seconds = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime))

                let secondsString = String(format: "%02d", seconds % 60)
                 let minutesAString = String(format: "%02d", seconds / 60)

                // move the slider

                if let duration = self.player?.currentItem?.duration {
                    let durationSeconds = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(duration))
                    print("value of duratioinSeconds: \(seconds))")
                    print("value of Seconds: \(durationSeconds)")

                     print(Float(seconds % durationSeconds))
                    self.Slider.setValue(Float(durationSeconds), animated: true)
                    self.Slider.minimumValue = 1
                    self.Slider.maximumValue = Float(durationSeconds)
                    self.Slider.value = Float(seconds % durationSeconds)
                }

            })
```

Comment: i am using AVAudioplayer.. this is giving error..
Value of type 'AVAudioPlayer' has no member 'addPeriodicTimeObserver'

Comment: please tell me solution according to AVAudioplayer

Comment: i given according to AVPlayer, i will try and give according to AVAudioPlayer

Comment: please tell me according to AVAudioplayer.. my project is at Deadline

Comment: can i send you whole file code? you can understand better what i am doing

Comment: Are you trying with progress View or slider?

Comment: i am trying with progressView

Comment: i have uiview and assign a class of progressView

Comment: you can use slider, easily you will get

Comment: i am trying this statement but app is crashing on this point
 progressView.setProgress(Float((player?.duration)!), animated: true)

Comment: but i need a view to fill the color

Comment: Try this   progressbar.setProgress(Float(player.currentTime), animated: true) . in my case it is working

Comment: Can you post the code , what exactly your requirement is.

Comment: check your mail

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you if you are using AVPlayer, I use it in one of my apps. It does require you setting the duration of the currently playing item. You can play with the `interval` property to adjust how frequently this method is run (which will change how smoothly the progressView changes)

```
let duration = playerItem.duration //set duration of currently playing item
let interval = CMTimeMake(1, 1)
player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { [weak self] time in
                let totalDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds((self?.duration)!)

                let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time)
                let currentProgress = Float(durationSeconds / totalDurationSeconds)
                self?.progressView.setProgress(currentProgress, animated: true)
            })
```

Comment: i am using AVAudioplayer.. this is giving error..
Value of type 'AVAudioPlayer' has no member 'addPeriodicTimeObserver' and playerItem

Comment: please tell me solution according to AVAudioplayer

Comment: Ahh that code will Work for AVPlayer. Sorry, should have checked what method you were using to play your audio.

Comment: please tell me according to AVAudioplayer.. my project is at Deadline

Comment: i am recording audio and then play that audio with AVAudioplayer

Comment: can i send you whole file code? you can understand better what i am doing

Comment: AVAudioPlayer has duration and currentTime properties. You can use a timer to fire every second and each time you can use those properties to work out the progress (like in my answer).

Comment: yeah i tried these properties but not worked.. if you can see my code then it may be easy to understand

Comment: i am trying this statement but app is crashing on this point
 progressView.setProgress(Float((player?.duration)!), animated: true)

Comment: If you update your question with more code and a more detailed explanation might be easier to help.